# How to clean up a child-component on unmount when using ref-callbacks and saving them into an array?

Tags: reactjs

Ok, so I've been scratching my head with this one for a while now.

I have a component which clones and saves a reference to each child component in a collection (with the ref-callback).

What I keep getting stuck with is how to unsubscribe this child when getting null in the ref-callback from the child's `componentWillUnmount`

I've thought about passing an unsubscribe-method back to the child, but keep getting stuck on where to store it. eg. `return () => this.subscribers.delete(newSubscriber)`

The last idea I had was to compare the subscribers-array with the new children in `componentWillUpdate` but it kind of feels like a compromise.

I might be missing something obvious here, so all input is welcome!

```
subscribe(child) { 
    const newSubscriber = { 
        component: child, 
        domNode: ReactDOM.findDOMNode(child), 
        ...otherStuff 
    }

    this.subscribers.add(newSubscriber);
}

render() {
    return React.Children
                .map(this.props.children, 
                     child => React.cloneElement(child, { ref: this.subscribe })
}
```

Attaching a basic example:

https://jsfiddle.net/2t78r2ro/1/